# <fieldset> not overflowing as expected in Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

With the Chrome 87 update, I started getting user-submitted bug reports because some of the fieldsets on a form started to overflow overtop of the content below it.

Here is a fiddle that shows the issue in its most reduced form:
http://jsfiddle.net/phanbu/69v1xa5m/21/

Even though the `.box` has

```
.box {
    // ...
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The contents overflow the container down the page.  The funny thing is that changing the `.box` from a `<fieldset>` to a `<div>` makes it overflow in the expected way:
https://jsfiddle.net/phanbu/6Lc4wrma/5/

Because this happens in Chromium, the updated version of Edge behaves in the same way.  Is this a Chromium bug, or is there a special thing about `<fieldset>` elements that I'm misunderstanding?

---

Update:

Based on the comments below, I've decided to set an absolute height on those `<fieldset>`s.  This means that when there are one or two checkboxes, there will be extra empty space in the element.

I could have converted them into `<div>`s for now.  But that would mean more changes in more places, and I want it to be as easy to change back as it can be.

Comment: Fieldsets sure are _somewhat_ special (think about their relation to `legend`, and how that gets displayed half inside the border, for example) - but I don’t think they should behave special in this particular regard. My money would rather be on “bug” here. I tried to check what default formatting Chrome applies to fieldset from the UA stylesheet, but nothing in there appeared particularly related to this issue.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with max-height.  Using height it will scroll.

Comment: looks like bug fixed in version 89 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151858

Comment: in fact, just updated chrome to Version 87.0.4280.88 and it is fixed in that already

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Thank you for the link to the Chromium bug page.

Comment: I wish I could get my users to upgrade to that browser version.  Oh well.

Comment: @PaulHanbury, you can try to update the MS Edge browser on your end to see whether it fixes the issue. if the issue gets fixed then you can try to post it as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  I have "Microsoft Edge is up to date. Version 87.0.664.55 (Official build) (64-bit)"  The issue still persists.

Comment: I can say that, like @GarrGodfrey said, going to Chrome 87.0.4280.88 does fix the issue in Chrome.

Comment: workaround is either a fixed height or a div within the fieldset to handle the scrolling/height

Comment: @PaulHanbury, I try to test the issue in Edge Canary, Dev, Beta and Stable version. Based on my test result, I found that the issue is fixed in the MS Edge Version 89.0.723.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit). See test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/cKxyBHD).